# Как вывести формулу из таблицы?

Tags: математика, c++

Ребят, я по моему забыл математику. Столкнулся с тривиальной задачей - необходимо выразить через формулу зависимость y от x - **f(x)=y**, согласно вот этой таблице данных:

### x 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

### y 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5

Comment: либо round(x/2), либо ceil(x/2). всяко может быть.

Comment: Метод наименьших квадратов в помощь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

так?

```
double f(const double x)
    {
      return floor((x-1)/2+1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Разумеется, так:

```
int f(int x)
{
    static const table[] = { 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5 };
    if (x < 1 || x > 10)
       throw std::invalid_argument("x");
    return table[x];
}
```

*Ваш К. О.*

---

Можно, конечно, `int f(int x) { return (x + 1)/2; }`, но это не отвечает требованиям, т. к. поведение в остальных точках не задано.